# openapi generator spring boot and client: post and receive file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openapi, openapi-generator

I am working on a spring boot server and client integration tests using the openapi-generator.

From what I understood, the openapi-generator can receive a file, and respond with a file if the following is declared in the yaml file:

```
  /processfile:
    post:
      summary: Processes a file containing data according to the ruleset specified.
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                ruleset:
                  type: string
                  description: Ruleset to use for processing. Use the ruleset name as specified in the ruleset properties file.
                file:
                  description: File to be processed.
                  type: string
                  format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The tokenized data.
          content:
            application/octet-stream:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
        '400':
          description: bad input parameter
```

For now I implemented the controller so that it can take care of the following mime-types: json, text/csv and AVRO.

Both the spring boot server and client are working fine, and they are performing as expected during unit tests.

However when I combine them in an integration test, sending a csv-file to the aforementioned Api. I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.web.client.UnknownContentTypeException: Could not extract response: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for response type [class java.io.File] and content type [text/csv]
```

And this with the following IT:

```
    @Test
    public void testCSVDatasetProcess() {
        String inputFileName = "MOCK_DATA.csv";
        String ruleset = "rulesetforcsv";

        File inputFile = new File("src/test/resources/datafiles/" + inputFileName);

        // process


        File response = api.processfilePost(ruleset,inputFile);

    }
```

(sorry if the test is a bit malformated, I have been playing a bit around).

Following this: https://community.smartbear.com/t5/Swagger-Open-Source-Tools/Improve-documentation-a-response-with-a-pdf-file-needs-schema/td-p/224501 . I was able to get it working, modifying the YAML like this:

```
  /processfile:
    post:
      summary: Processes a file containing data according to the ruleset specified.
      requestBody:
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              type: object
              properties:
                ruleset:
                  type: string
                  description: Ruleset to use for processing. Use the ruleset name as specified in the ruleset properties file.
                file:
                  description: File to be processed.
                  type: string
                  format: binary
      responses:
        '200':
          description: The tokenized data.
          content:
            application/octet-stream:
              schema:
                type: string
                format: byte <---- this changed
        '400':
          description: bad input parameter
```

The response is now a byte array (ResponseEntity<byte[]>) and not a File (ResponseEntity). I can then write a byte array to a file if I want.

Although this works, I was wondering if there is a better way to deal with this, keeping the input and output type consistent, in the sense that posting a file, would return you a file.

note: I haven't implemented a HttpMessageConverter since I am assuming that this would come out of the box with the openapi-generator application and that the fault is rather on my malformed definitions in the YAML file.

Thanks for the response!